# JAR File Won't Run (MacOS)

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

So, I spent a pretty substantial amount of time building a 2D dungeon crawler. It works perfectly when I debug it in Intellij, but when I build the artifact that creates an application for my computer, it doesn't run. To clarify, it actually 
[builds the application...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20gyg.png)

...but none of the files, not even the JAR, will open upon double-clicking. Here's everything in my manifest file, which I'm told is of some importance:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: /Users/Adrian/IdeaProjects/Dungeons/src/sample/Main.java
Main-Class: sample.Main
```

I'm brand new to this, but to me it seems that I've wasted my time building this application that won't run. Some other information:
1. I'm running MacOS 10.13.3.
2. I'm using Intellij IDEA CE 2018.1 to build the game.
3. The project incorporates copious amounts of Java FX.

Any and all help is much appreciated.

EDIT: I now receive the following error message: `fsctl error: Operation not permitted, using HARDCODED low disk threshold 10737418240 for volume_size: 121123069952` Does this mean that I, for some reason, need more disk space?

Comment: Drop to the command line and run the Jar manually (`java -jar TheNameOfYourJar.jar`) - check what output you get

Comment: You probably need to build a fatjar. (All your dependencies are missing in the jar file)

Comment: Your manifest’s `Class-Path` line is invalid.  It should be removed.  (Normally it is a space-separated list of *relative URLs* of other .jar files on which the containing .jar file depends.)

Comment: Practice with a "Hello World" program, not your real app, no dependencies, just the simplest little app. Go through all the steps: compile, build, `.jar`, launch.

Comment: @BasilBourque Okay, so I've tried this. The result is several copies of the same console error message: `fsctl error: Operation not permitted, using HARDCODED low disk threshold 10737418240 for volume_size: 121123069952`  Does this mean that I, for some reason, need more disk space?

Comment: @vbquestions Post this further detail as edits on your Question, not as a Comment.